# How to show details when click on list item in fragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have created a navigation drawer using fragments. When I click on one of the Drawer Item I am able to show a `ListView` in the `Fragment`. Now, I want to show detailed data for each List Item when I click on List Item. What can I do? Please suggest how I can do this.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new TutorialFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ProgramsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

TutorialFragment.java

```
public class TutorialFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] values = new String[] { "C Introduction", "Decision and Loops",
            "C Functions", "Arrays and Strings", "C Pointers",
            "Structure & Union", "C Files I/O", "C Enumeration",
            "C Preprocessors", "C Library Functions", "C Programming Examples" };

    ListView lvTutorial;

    public TutorialFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container,
                false);

        ListView lvTutorial = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvTutorial);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        lvTutorial.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvTutorial.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + values[position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /* Here instead Toast I want to show details of each Tutorial Topic in another fragment. */
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

In above ListView suppose I click on C Pointers then detailed Tutorial must be open using another fragment.
In this fragment I want to send name of file in another fragment and open that file in that fragment.

DetailedTutorial.java

```
    public class DetailedTutorial extends Fragment{

    TextView txtView;
    String filename,line;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detailedtutorial, container, false);

//      txtView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
//      filename = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("filename");
//      
//      line = "";
//      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//      InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);
//      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
//      
//      try {
//          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//              builder.append(builder);
//          }
//      } catch (IOException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

        /*In this fragment I want to show details of each List Item in TutorialFragment.java
          I want to take name of List Item from TutorialFragment.java and open that file from raw folder to show detail in TextView.*/

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

In this fragment I want to show details of each List Item in TutorialFragment.java
              I want to take name of List Item from TutorialFragment.java and open that file from raw folder to show detail in TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Fragment fragment = new ExperienceDetailsFragmentActivity(); // object
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // next
                                                                                // fragment
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("companyNameString",
                        "abc");


                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with
                // this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
```

Comment: You can use this cod  inside  onItemClick, instead of Toast

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("companyNameString",
                        "abc");   what is use of this? Why you used it?

Comment: To send values from one fragment to another fragment

Comment: Then which is value and which one is key? How to access that value in another fragment ?

Comment: First one key, and second one is value

Comment: I want to send list item name to another fragment. How can I access it in another fragment?

Comment: Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
  companyNameString = bundle.getString("companyNameString");

Answer (score 0):

Use interface to communicate between list and detail fragments, below example may helps

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-using-fragments--mobile-13886

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new fragment for detail and add new fragment over current fragment and pass the detail value of info to new fragment like below**

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    fm.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragOne = new MyFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("ValueofListPostion", position);
   `fragOne.setArguments(arguments);
    ft.add(R.id.main_frag_container, fragOne);
    ft.addToBackStack("AnyString")l
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: on Item Click listner of your list view